# Onclick add text to a div

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I just started learning Javascript, but I really thought I knew this. I can't figure out why it won't work. I need it to insert "this text" formatted as a level 2 header into `theDiv` when the button is clicked. I've tried every way, even with a function. This example seems like the way it should work, but doesn't. I have to make this work with Javascript only, no JQuery - I don't know any yet.

```
<html>
  <h1 id="header">Header in progress</h1>
  <body>
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML('This is new.')">
    </p>
    <h3><div id="theDiv"></div></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("theDiv").textContent = 'This is dynamically added text';
```

Comment: @Uni: my pleasure, please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = 'This is new.'`

You need to pass `id` of div with in `''(quotes)` and `innerHTML` is property not a function

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EdyX4/)

Comment: Wow that was quick for a upvote... Outside of that agreed, the issue is you don't wrap your div name in ''.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that, but it still doesn't do anything (see updated code)

Answer (score 0):

first step:  get your button, and your html elements.
2nd step : add click listener to the button
3th step: add text into your html element.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('theButton');
const myText = document.getElementById('theDiv');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const myInsertText = 'Hello World !';
myText.innerHTML = myInsertText;

});
```

```html
 <button id='theButton'>bouton</button>
 <p id="theDiv"></p>
```